# How can I group by and count list value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'session_id': ['T01', 'T02', 'T03', 'T04', 'T05', 'T06', 'T07'],
                   'path': [array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='<U1'),
                            array(['x', 'y', 'z'], dtype='<U1'),
                            array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='<U1'),
                            array(['x', 'y', 'z'], dtype='<U1'),
                            array(['k'], dtype='<U1'),
                            array(['x', 'y', 'z'], dtype='<U1'),
                            array(['h', 'i'], dtype='<U1')],
                   'flag': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                   'total_value': [0.02, 0.05, 0.02, 0.05, 0.001, 0.05, 0.03]})
```

like this table below

```
| session_id |         path         | flag  |   total_value |
| ---------- | -------------------- | ----- | ------------- |
| T01        | [a,b,c]              | 0     | 0.020         |
| T02        | [x,y,z]              | 1     | 0.050         |
| T03        | [a,b,c]              | 0     | 0.020         |
| T04        | [x,y,z]              | 0     | 0.050         |
| T05        | [k]                  | 0     | 0.001         |
| T06        | [x,y,z]              | 1     | 0.050         |
| T07        | [h,i]                | 0     | 0.030         |
```

I want to group by path, flag, total_value and count number of records after that sort by total_value desc. Final result choose be like this below.

```
|         path         | flag  |   total_value |  count  |
| -------------------- | ----- | ------------- | ------- |
| [x,y,z]              | 1     | 0.050         |  2      |
| [x,y,z]              | 0     | 0.050         |  1      |
| [h,i]                | 0     | 0.030         |  1      |
| [a,b,c]              | 0     | 0.020         |  2      |
| [k]                  | 0     | 0.001         |  1      |
```

I try to used

```
df.groupby(['path', 'flag', 'total_value']).count()
```

but error will show

```
unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Comment: error: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: could you include this dataframe as a dictionary in your question?

Comment: How can I do? @enke

Comment: sorry I not sure about your question, but this dataset has created by this code

Comment: from collections import defaultdict

df_paths = df.groupby('session_id')['event_name'].aggregate(
  lambda x: x.tolist()).reset_index()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with that groupby is that as the error message says, `np.ndarray`s are mutable hence, unhashable, so cannot be used as an index. But tuples are hashable, so you can convert the arrays in the `'path'` column to tuples and `groupby` on the desired columns and use `count` method.

Then after the operation, convert `'path'` values back to `np.array`s:

```
df['path'] = df['path'].apply(tuple)
out = df.groupby(['path', 'flag', 'total_value']).count().reset_index()
out['path'] = out['path'].apply(np.array)
```

Output:

```
        path  flag  total_value  session_id
0  [a, b, c]     0        0.020           2
1     [h, i]     0        0.030           1
2        [k]     0        0.001           1
3  [x, y, z]     0        0.050           1
4  [x, y, z]     1        0.050           2
```